# default ODI user for multiple user installation on same server

Tags: oracle, shell, oracle-data-integrator

i have two ODI instances installed on the same machine with the same home directory.

i am trying to import scenarios using ./startcmd.sh command and it is working but it is always deploy the scenario to instance1.

the question is where i can redirect the deployment to instance2 instead of instance1?

are there any properties file or something else providing that ?

Answer (score 0):

A scenario is not imported into an instance / path on the machine. It's imported in a work repository in a database.

`OdiImportScen` does not have a parameter to specify the repository in which you want to import.
Instead you can use [`OdiImportObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/122126/odi/reference/GUID-49BACA0A-54F1-4D0C-92C8-21A762B9F6BF.htm#GUID-100A9946-2367-40C3-802E-01D2D65FEC01) and specify the `WORKREPNAME` parameter.